# Google Analytics Android Real Time

Tags: android, google-analytics, real-time, analytics

I'm trying to implement Analytics on my app. Actually I did it, but I'm not able to see interactivity in real time, it's takes some time, like 2~3 minutes to appear something. I tried to set Dispatch Period but it didn't take effect.

I followed the implementation of Google Analytics Developer, some code below:

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER // Tracker used only in this app.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

            Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(2);

            // Set the log level to verbose.
            GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger()
                    .setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);

            // Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

The code to send:

```
private static void SendView(Activity act, String view) {
    // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((AppController) act.getApplication())
            .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    // Set screen name.
    // Where path is a String representing the screen name.
    t.setScreenName(BuildName(view));

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jackcar, did you solve the problem. I have encountered same issue here. And seems there is no work around so far.

Comment: Hello Arthur, no I didn't find it. I guess there is no solution for this problem until now.

Comment: Seems like so. Google haven't complete their integration between Analytics and Play services so far, we have to wait..

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't do immediate dispatch with Google Play Services.

This is done to save traffic.

> On devices with Google Play Services installed, by default, auto dispatching with 2 minute interval is enabled and manual dispatching is not available.
> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

What it doesn't say is that these 2 minutes can only be increased programmatically. iOS has a similar system, but the time frame is a bit different. Either 1 minute or 30 seconds.

Generally, you don't want to look at the real time GA data to debug your
tracking implementation. Have a wrapper around your GA/Firebase library and have logging in that wrapper.

Additioanlly, the Real time data reports in GA are severely lacking dimensions and aggregation options. You want to wait for a day or two for the data to be made properly available.